# Consuming Rest Service the functional way

Tags: java, rest, java-8, lazy-evaluation, java-stream

So I was curious as to how would the following code be rewritten more effiently with the java8 streams API.

```
public static List<FlightInfo> getResults(String origin,List<String> destinations)  {

    final String uri = "https://api.searchflight.com/;
    List<FlightInfo> results = new LinkedList<FlightInfo>();

    for(String destination:destinations) {


            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

            String params = getParams(origin,destination);
            FlightInfo result = restTemplate.postForObject(uri+params,FlightInfo.class);

            results.add(result);
    }

    return results;

}
```

After this method is done doing what its is doing and I receive the list of FLightInfo objects, I am converting it into a stream and will be doing various transformations on it (group by, etc). Now it is pretty apparant that this is a long running operation. Furthermore it actually combines multiple rest calls to the web service, so I already have most of the data obtained by the time I make the last call, but I would not  start processing it before the whole method returns.

Is there a way to do all that a bit more reactively? Could I return a stream immediatelly and have the operations on that stream process data as it comes down the pipe or this is a bit too much to ask? How would that be done in Java 8. That

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well it all depends on when you need the outcome. If you wish it to be sequential, this below is still a decent way as its lazy. But it would boil at a terminal operation (say during `collect`).

```
public static Stream<FlightInfo> getResults(String origin,List<String> destinations)  {
    final String uri = "https://api.searchflight.com/";
    return destinations.stream().map(destination -> {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        String params = getParams(origin,destination);
        FlightInfo result = restTemplate.postForObject(uri+params,FlightInfo.class);
        return result;
    })    
}
```

Or I would do it with `destinations.stream().parallel()` if I can. This is a reasonable outcome in most circumstances. But still it will not start processing it in parallel till the time you call a terminal operation for it. Which absolutely makes sense.

But it looks to me that you wish for a producer-consumer type of a thing. For which:

```
public static CompletableFuture<List<FlightInfo>> getResults(String origin,List<String> destinations)  {
    final String uri = "https://api.searchflight.com/";
    List<CompletableFuture<FlightInfo>> collect = destinations
           .stream()
           .map(destination -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
                 RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
                 String params = getParams(origin,destination);
                 FlightInfo result = restTemplate.postForObject(uri+params,FlightInfo.class);
                 return result;            
           })).collect(Collectors.toList());
    return sequence(collect);       //line-1 
}

public static <T> CompletableFuture<List<T>> sequence(List<CompletableFuture<T>> com) {
    return CompletableFuture.allOf(com.toArray(new CompletableFuture[com.size()]))
            .thenApply(v -> com.stream()
                            .map(CompletableFuture::join)
                            .collect(Collectors.toList())
            );
}
```

For **simplicity**, at `line-1` you can simply return `collect` instead of `sequence(collect)`. You can then iterate over the list to fetch each value.

But with `sequence`, you have a single CompletableFuture object to worry about, which you can then check for values at once if completed.

Comment: So is it correct to say that the completable future approach shall overlap processing with fetching the results as well. By the looks of it, this is really the producer consumer mapped to use streams. In that case what would you say are the benefits of this particular approach over implementing producer - consumer (apart from brevity and lack of boilerplate of course). By the way  I am really thankful for the solution provided and I think it is great. I am just trying to understand better and thats why asking the questions. Thanks again

Comment: Simply that above CompletableFuture provides a nice abstraction for producer consumer. Well if it looks ugly, which it is but if the occurrence of above pattern is high over the code base then I recommend looking at http://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki . It provides nice abstractions as Observables (you can think of like a stream) to which you can have results once available. Because abstractions are sound, you have a firm grip of expressiveness